# XMLSerialization of derived class

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I have two classes, one is the base class

```
public abstract class BaseBon : BaseRecord
{
    public BaseBon(Nat recordIndicator) : base(recordIndicator)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Waehrungkennzeichen - CurrencyCode
    /// </summary>
    protected FixedString m_CurrencyCode = new FixedString(3);
    public String CurrencyCode
    {
        get { return m_CurrencyCode.Value; }
        set { m_CurrencyCode.Value = value; }
    }

}
```

and one which is derived from it.
The derived class uses a different kind of currencyCode so I used `new`
to tell the compiler that it should use this implementation instead.
But when I want to serialize it, it throws an error in my unitTest

```
/// <summary>
/// Waehrungkennzeichen - CurrencyCode
/// </summary>
private new FixedInt m_CurrencyCode = new FixedInt(1);
[XmlElement("CurrencyCode_Small",typeof(CurrencyCode?))]
public new CurrencyCode? CurrencyCode
{
    get
    {
        CurrencyCode? val = null;
        Array values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(CurrencyCode));
        foreach (CurrencyCode value in values)
        {
            if (value.GetValue().Equals(m_CurrencyCode.Value))
            {
                val = value;
                break;
            }
        }
        return val;
    }
    set
    {
        if (!value.Equals(null))
        {
            m_CurrencyCode.Value = (int)value;
        }
    }
}
```

The error is of type System.InvalidOperationException.
I can only give you a brief translation because I only have the german translation.
The error states that I mask the attribute CurrencyCode of the base class and that I should use the XmlElementAttribute to give it a new name. How should I do it ? Because I allready use the `XmlElement`

Comment: I think source of error at mismatch of types: return CurrencyCode? and at attribute Currency code. You must use the same type in both cases.

Comment: changed it but it doesn't work either

Comment: The problem would be your `public new CurrencyCode`, I don't see why you couldn't give it a new name, as it clearly conflicts with the existing defined name. Which would enable the question, is your class really based on your BaseBon, or not. Why not supply a new property that is called EnumCurrencyCode, and leave the  existing serialization as it is?

Comment: @Icepickle This library, to which the sourcecode belongs, is a port from another language. So the class is based on the BaseBon when it comes to the documentation. Currently I am using your approach but I was wondering if I could simply avoid it ;)